# How to monitor file modifications and know what changes were made

Tags: java, filesystems, file-monitoring

I'm working on a Java project where I need to monitor files in a certain directory and be notified whenever changes are made on one of the files, this can be achieved using `WatchService`. Furthermore, I want to know what changes were made, for example: "characters 10 to 15 where removed", "at index 13 characters 'abcd' were added"... I'm willing to take any solution even based on c language monitiring the fileSystem.
I also want to avoid the diff solution to avoid storing the same file 2 times, and for the complexity of the algorithm, it takes to much time for big files.
Thank you for help. :)

Comment: Please give us more information. What operating system do you have? Do you have control over the filesystem? A layered filesystem could in theory record the changes (and thus reduce the amount of required storage), however, it would still need to do a diff on each changed file.

Comment: Well, you have one part covered already, that is detecting what files have changed; as to the other part, there are diff libraries. Have you "scouted" any, yet?

Comment: well for the first question, I'm working on windows, but coding a specific OS solution is also an alternative, and I have physical access to and full control of the machine. also why should I still need to a diff If I know what changes werw made.
for the second question, I didn't check yet for diff libraries because I don't want to use them.

Comment: I don0t k now if can be applicable in your solution, but something like SVN could be a solution. You can have a tracing system based on a diff tracking DB. You could you SVN as applicative or (SVN is GPL) you can look at its source code.

Comment: Indeed I thought on checking the source code of git, but I think they are using diff, I think if I don't get any answer I will go there, thanks for your comment thought :)

Comment: On Windows you can use filesystem filter driver that will let you know about operations and their parameters when they are performed. But this is platform-specific solution and can't be used from Java without significant effort in C coding.

Comment: thank you Eugene for your answer do you have any available code that could help (c code is Fine with me), also if you post the code as an answer I could mark the post as answered (at least partially :) )

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux, then the following code will detect changes in file length, you can easily extend this to update modifications.

Because you don't want to keep two files, there is no way to tell which characters were altered if either the file length is reduced (lost characters can't be found) or The file was altered somewhere in the middle

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd = open("test", O_RDONLY);
    int length = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    while (1)
    {
        int new_length;
        close(fd);
        open("test", O_RDONLY);
        sleep(1);
        new_length = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        printf("new_length = %d\n", new_length);
        if (new_length != length)
            printf ("Length changed! %d->%d\n", length, new_length);
        length=new_length;
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
Since the author accepts changes to the kernel for this task, the following change to vfs_write should do the trick:

```
#define MAX_DIFF_LENGTH 128
ssize_t vfs_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
    char old_content[MAX_DIFF_LENGTH+1];
    char new_content[MAX_DIFF_LENGTH+1];
    ssize_t ret;

    if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_WRITE))
        return -EBADF;
    if (!file->f_op || (!file->f_op->write && !file->f_op->aio_write))
        return -EINVAL;
    if (unlikely(!access_ok(VERIFY_READ, buf, count)))
        return -EFAULT;

    ret = rw_verify_area(WRITE, file, pos, count);
    if (___ishay < 20)
    {
        int i;
        int length = count > MAX_DIFF_LENGTH ? MAX_DIFF_LENGTH : count;
        ___ishay++;
        vfs_read(file, old_content, length, pos);
        old_content[length] = 0;
        new_content[length] = 0;
        memcpy(new_content, buf, length);
        printk(KERN_ERR"[___ISHAY___]Write request for file named: %s count: %d pos: %lld:\n", 
                file->f_path.dentry->d_name.name,
                count,
                *pos);
        printk(KERN_ERR"[___ISHAY___]New content (replacement) <%d>:\n", length);

        for (i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            printk("[0x%02x] (%c)", new_content[i], (new_content[i] > 32 && new_content[i] < 127) ? 
                    new_content[i] : 46);
            if (length+1 % 10 == 0)
                printk("\n");
        }
        printk(KERN_ERR"[___ISHAY___]Old content (on file now):\n");
        for (i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            printk("[0x%02x] (%c)", old_content[i], (old_content[i] > 32 && old_content[i] < 127) ? 
                    old_content[i] : 46);
            if (length+1 % 10 == 0)
                printk("\n");
        }

    }
    if (ret >= 0) {
        count = ret;
        if (file->f_op->write)
            ret = file->f_op->write(file, buf, count, pos);
        else
            ret = do_sync_write(file, buf, count, pos);
        if (ret > 0) {
            fsnotify_modify(file);
            add_wchar(current, ret);
        }
        inc_syscw(current);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Explanation:
vfs_write is the function that handles write requests for files, so that's our best central hook to catch modification requests for files before they occur.
vfs_write accepts the file, file position, buffer and length for the write operation, so we know what part of the file will be replaced by this write, and what data will replace it.

Since we know what part of the file will be altered, I added the vfs_read call just before the actual write to keep in memory the part of file we are about to overrun.

This should be a good starter point to get what you need, I made the following simplifications as this is only an example:

- Buffers are allocated statically at max 128 bytes (should be allocated dynamically and protect the memory allocation from wasting too much memory on huge write requests)
- File length should be checked and read buffer should refer to this check, the current code prints a read buffer even if the write overflows to length beyond the file end
- The output currently goes to dmesg. A better implementation would be to keep a cyclic buffer accessible in debugfs, possibly with poll option
- Current code captures write to ALL files, I'm sure that's not what you want...

[EDIT2]
Forgot to mention where this function is located, its under `fs/read_write.c` in the kernel tree

[EDIT3]
There's another possible solution, providing you know which program you want to monitor, and that it doesn't have libc linked statically is use [LD_PRELOAD](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) to override the `write` function and use that as your hook and record the changes. I haven't tried this, but there's no reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: thank you for answer but it's far from answering my problem, you might want to delete it

Comment: As I wrote: this is as far as you can go without keeping at least part of the original file in memory or other storage. The reason is the underlying OS does not notify you on file changes. A real solution must be implemented in kernel space. I hardly think this is far from solving the presented problem, care to explain?

Comment: well my problem is not to find which file was changed, I can do that using java code and in more efficient way, my problem , as explained in my question, is to find what change was made removal of character, replacement of character...
Thanks thought for trying to help
(a kernel space solution is also something I would care to get help about)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your efforts, I uped the answer, I will check it as answered when I try it, and I also hop to find another answer that doesn't need kernel modification